# vb.net combobox population getting index of the 1st combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I populated my combobox1 with this code in load

```
sql = "select name1,id1 from table1"
da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, "cbtbl1")
ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables("cbtbl1")
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = ds.Tables("cbtbl1").Columns("name1").Caption
```

I have my 2nd combobox2 related to combobox1. I inserted this code in combobox1 `selectedvaluechanged`. This to change to value of combobox2 based on their related ids

```
sql = "select name2,id2 from table2 where id1=" & ???????
da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, "cbtbl2")
ComboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables("cbtbl2")
ComboBox2.DisplayMember = ds.Tables("cbtbl2").Columns("name2").Caption
```

In my code i have question marks. It supposed to be the id of table1 which i don't know how to get :( or what to put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ValueMember` of Combobox1 to be the ID you retrieved from the database and the use the `SelectedValue` property to retrieve the ID of the selected item.

I don't think it's gonna work unless you specify the `ValueMember` property when you databind Combobox1, so don't forget to do that first.

OK, I knocked something together quickly with a database I am working on at the moment (it's OLEDB, but shouldn't matter for this)

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim test As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [ID], [名前] FROM [Tレイヤ管理]", DBConnections.PrimaryAccessDBConnection)
    Call test.Fill(ds, "testTable")

    Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables("testTable")
    Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
    Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "名前"

    AddHandler Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged, AddressOf Something

End Sub

Private Sub Something(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Call MessageBox.Show(String.Format("ID {0}", Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue))

End Sub
```

I get the ID showing just fine with this.

UPDATE:

If this still doesn't work then you can get the selected item this way:

Private Sub Something(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

```
    Dim selectedItem As DataRowView = CType(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)

    Call MessageBox.Show(String.Format("ID {0} Name {1}", New Object() {selectedItem("ID"), selectedItem("名前")}))

End Sub
```

Comment: I assign `ComboBox1.ValueMember = ds.Tables("cbtbl1").Columns("id1").Caption` yet i don't know how to retriev it when selecting a value from combo1. I tried `sql = "select name2,id2 from table2 where idtable1=1" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString` but it returns `System.Data.DataRowView`

Comment: I knocked together an example quickly and this works. So if yours doesn't then you must be missing a step somewhere.

Comment: I got the ID now, i checked it and it was right. The thing is i dont know why my combobox2 is not changing values.

Comment: I see as i select choices from combo1, my combo2 just continue to add the value in the bottom. how do i reset it so that it will not append?

Comment: You should reset the items in Combobox2 each time if you don't want that to happen. Just call `Combobox2.Items.Clear()` before adding the new items.